# How to sort rows in a excel sheet and print to a file using VB script?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table named student . I am trying to print corresponding student names with respect to his mark . I want to print to a file using Excel macro .

My table which contain title as student name 1 , 2, 3 etc.. and corresponding marks as 1 , 2, 3 ,4 and "-" .

[image]

I want to write function in VB to sort corresponding rows as each subject (0,1,2,3,...7) and also print the values to a file .

**output (file.txt)**

```
NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
STUDENT 2 ,STUDENT 5 ,STUDENT 4 ,NULL,NULL
STUDENT 4,STUDENT 5,NULL,NULL,NULL
etc..
```

columns in a row should sort to ascending order and if "-" present in any column should be print as NULL as remaining values .

I have written

```
Sub test()
'create and write into file txt
Dim fso As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim Fileout As Object
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("MyFile.txt", True, True)

    'Write logic for sorting 

    Fileout.Close

End Sub
```

How to sort in a excel using VB script and print those rows ?

Comment: Do you want VBScript or VBA? They are not the same thing

Comment: VB script for excel

Comment: Since you mention Excel Macro, and your example code is VBA I'm going to assume yo mean VBA and not VBScript. You can revert it if this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way of implementing that, adapt it to your needs:

```
' Naive O(N^2) sort
Sub Sort(arr() As Long, students() As String)
    If UBound(arr) <= 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr) - 1
        ' Look for the minimum index in the sub-array going from i
        Dim indexOfMin As Long
        indexOfMin = i
        For j = i To UBound(arr)
            If arr(j) < arr(indexOfMin) Then
                indexOfMin = j
            End If
        Next j
        ' Put the minimum mark at the beginning of the sub-array
        Dim tmp As Variant
        tmp = arr(i)
        arr(i) = arr(indexOfMin)
        arr(indexOfMin) = tmp
        ' Put the student with the minimum value at the beginning of the students sub-array
        tmp = students(i)
        students(i) = students(indexOfMin)
        students(indexOfMin) = tmp
    Next i
End Sub

Sub SortAndSave()
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = Range("A1:F9")

    Dim data As Variant
    data = dataRange.Value

    Dim NSubject As Long, NStudents As Long
    NSubject = UBound(data, 1) - 1
    NStudents = UBound(data, 2) - 1

    Dim text As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To NSubject
        ' Read marks and students names
        Dim subjectMarks() As Long
        ReDim subjectMarks(0 To NStudents - 1)
        Dim students() As String
        ReDim students(0 To NStudents - 1)
        For j = 1 To NStudents
            ' Use a big enough number 999 so that students with no mark will be pushed to the end
            subjectMarks(j - 1) = IIf(data(i + 1, j + 1) <> "-", data(i + 1, j + 1), 999)
            students(j - 1) = data(1, j + 1)
        Next j

        ' Sort marks and students
        Sort subjectMarks, students

        ' Build display row for subject
        Dim row As String
        row = ""
        For j = 1 To NStudents
            ' If there is a mark render the student name
            If subjectMarks(j - 1) <> 999 Then
                row = row & students(j - 1)
            ' Otherwise render NULL
            Else
                row = row & "NULL"
            End If
            ' Add a comma if not the latest
            If j <> NStudents Then
                row = row & ","
            End If
        Next j
        text = text & row
        ' Add a \r\n if not the latest
        If i <> NSubject Then
            text = text & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Result:

```
NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
STUDENT 2,STUDENT 5,STUDENT 4,NULL,NULL
STUDENT 4,STUDENT 5,NULL,NULL,NULL
STUDENT 4,STUDENT 5,NULL,NULL,NULL
STUDENT 2,STUDENT 5,STUDENT 4,NULL,NULL
STUDENT 5,STUDENT 4,STUDENT 2,STUDENT 1,NULL
STUDENT 5,STUDENT 4,STUDENT 2,STUDENT 1,NULL
STUDENT 4,STUDENT 5,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: This answer uses VBA, not VBScript

Comment: Indeed, but I've drawn the same conclusion as you: the OP wants VBA. :) Otherwise he will tell us...

Comment: I want VBA . Thanks for your valuable support

Comment: @Pragmateek Getting "type mismatch error" in line  subjectMarks(j - 1) = IIf(data(i + 1, j + 1) <> "-", data(i + 1, j + 1), 999) while running the script

Comment: @user2986042 You probably have a wrong value in your data range, i.e. which is neither `-` or an integer.